# WatchKit basic text animations

Tags: ios, animation, watchkit, wkinterfacegroup

Is it possible to reproduce the basic animations we can see on the demo page : http://www.apple.com/watch/health-and-fitness/

We can see some text appearing/disappearing. 
I wonder if they did it, can we make it too or we don't have access to the methods yet...

I know animations are pretty limited on watchKit but can we make something with NSTimer and WKInterfacegroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my answer :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/94672/watchkit-faq

> Can I use Core Graphics to generate images dynamically and then use them in a watch app? Can they be cached on the watch?
>
> Yes, but the composition of any images using Core Graphics must take place on the iPhone as part of the extension. Once you have rendered the Core Graphics drawing context into an instance of UIImage you can then cache it on the watch using addCachedImage(_:name:) from WKInterfaceDevice.